# Remove empty properties of knockout viewModel

Tags: javascript, c#, knockout.js

This turned out to be harder that I thought. I have a ViewModel which I use specifically for filtering in my grids. Here it is:

```
var GridFiltersViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.search = ko.observable();
    self.sortColumn = ko.observable();
    self.sortDirectionIsAscending = ko.observable(true);
    self.page = ko.observable(1);
    self.pageSize = ko.observable(10);
    self.pageCount = ko.observable();
    self.itemCount = ko.observable();
};
```

The issue I'm faced with is when I send an instance of this ViewModel towards my action method I get an error:

> The value 'null' is not valid for *property*

This happens because my server-side ViewModel properties do not accept the `null` and `undefined` properties of the client-side ViewModel even when I set them as nullable. The only way to have the server-side ViewModel accept the empty properties is to not send them at all. This is my attempt at that:

```
var GridFiltersViewModel = function () {
    // the properties from before

    self.removeEmptyProperties = function () {
        for (var property in self) {
            if (self[property] === null || self[property] === undefined) {
                delete self[property];
            }
        }
    };
};
```

Suffice to say, it does not work. Currently I just end up with an `undefined` object when the method finishes. I've also tried converting the knockout ViewModel into a JavaScript object (using `ko.toJS()`) before running the method but I get the same result.

What am I doing wrong here and how do I do it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just construct a new JSON object and return that rather than try something exotic like removing properties... something like this:

```
 var GridFiltersViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.prop1 = ko.observable(null);
    self.prop2 = ko.observable('Test');
    self.prop3 = ko.observable(undefined);
    self.definedProperties = ko.computed(function () {
        var json = {};
        json.props = "";
        for (var property in self) {
            if (self[property]() !== null && self[property]() !== undefined) {
                json[property] = self[property]();
                if (json.props !== "") {
                  json.props += ", ";                   
                }
                json.props += property;
            }
        }
        return json;
    });    
};
```

Full example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/brettwgreen/ehy7cmud/2/

Comment: Note also, though, that you weren't unboxing your observable checks by using parentheses... so you would get back raw function objects in your original code when checking self[property]. Should be self[property](). Might be the source of your pain.

Comment: The parentheses aren't the source of my pain but it doesn't matter, your solution worked great!